# hexdump output order

Tags: hexdump

I am playing with the Unix hexdump utility. My input file is UTF-8 encoded, containing a single character `ñ`, which is `C3 B1` in hexadecimal UTF-8.

```
hexdump test.txt
0000000 b1c3
0000002
```

Huh? This shows `B1 C3` - the inverse of what I expected! Can someone explain?

For getting the expected output I do:

```
hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  c3 b1                                             |..|
00000002
```

I was thinking I understood encoding systems.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: This seems to explain why `xxd` and `hexdump` show different results!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is because hexdump defaults to using 16-bit words and you are running on a little-endian architecture. The byte sequence `b1 c3` is thus interpreted as the hex word `c3b1`. The `-C` option forces hexdump to work with bytes instead of words.

Comment: I was thinking it must have something to do with endianness.

Comment: but why hexdump default to this confusing output format? is there any historic reason?

Comment: What's confusing is the propensity for humans to encode numbers in big-endian order. Little-endian is more logical, which is why it's used on many CPU architectures, including x86, in spite of the awkwardness.

Comment: Actually big-endian and little-endian each have their strengths and weaknesses. Neither is "more logical" in an absolute sense.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, what's confusing is that it assumes 16bit words little endian. What is the logic in choosing 16bit words? Or any other word length? IMO makes more sense to default to big endian representation which would look the same regardless of word length thus much less confusing in this use case.

Comment: Purely conjecture, but the historic reason is almost certainly that hexdump was initially implemented on a little endian machine that used 16 bit words and it was a perfectly reasonable default.

Answer (score 5):

I found two ways to avoid that:

```
hexdump -C file
```

or

```
od -tx1 < file
```

I think it is stupid that hexdump decided that files are usually 16bit word little endian. Very confusing IMO.

Comment: While hexdump defaults to using 16-bit words, I think the endianness depends on the architecture it's running on

Comment: @erwaman, true. Tried with `podman run --rm -ti --arch s390x --entrypoint /bin/sh quay.io/centos/centos:stream9` and then install `util-linux` to get `hexdump`. And without flags it showed big endian format.