# Endianness when writing to disk

Tags: endianness

I am working on a little endian system. Suppose I have the following data that I write to a sector in a disk:

```
$ hexdump file
04eb 0008 ...
$ cat file > /dev/sdb
```

Now when I read it back to memory, how will it look like in the memory and why?

Comment: unless you specifically requestion an endianness conversion as the data's read or written to/from disk, memory address #0 of the data will be byte #0 of the data on disk, mem #1 -> byte #1, mem #2 -> byte #2, etc... and the same would happen on reading. byte #0 goes into mem #0, byte #1 -> mem #1.

Comment: @Marc: What I see is eb04 0800...Why is that?

Comment: `hexdump` might be doing endianness conversion.

Comment: @nneonneo: How do I turn that off?

Comment: @nneonneo: Found it...it is -C..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847360/hexdump-confusion