# Perl pack integer

Tags: perl, binary, pack

Considering this value:

```
my $value = hex('0x12345678');
```

And I would like my `hexdump` to be like this (same bits order):

```
0000000 1234 5678
```

I used this method but it mixes up my value:

```
open(my $out, '>:raw', 'foo') or die "Unable to open: $!";     
print $out pack('l', $value);  # Test in little endian
print $out pack('l>', $value); # Test in big endian
```

Here's what I get:

```
0000000 5678 1234 3412 7856
```

How can I get the bits in order?

**EDIT**

So the problem might come from my hexdump, because I get the same output with the suggested answer.

```
$ perl -e 'print pack $_, 0x12345678 for qw( l> N )' | hexdump
0000000 3412 7856 3412 7856
```

I got the correct result with `hexdump -C`:

```
$ perl -e 'print pack $_, 0x12345678 for qw( l> N )' | hexdump -C
00000000  12 34 56 78 12 34 56 78                           |.4Vx.4Vx|
```

And I found the explanation here: 
[hexdump confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847360/hexdump-confusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'l>'` option works for me (note there's no call to `hex`, though). Also, `N` as the template works:

```
perl -e 'print pack $_, 0x12345678 for qw( l> N )' | xxd
0000000: 1234 5678 1234 5678
```

Comment: `perl -E'say 0x12345678 == hex("0x12345678")'`

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, but the quotes are missing in the question.

Comment: Yes, so Perl's `hex` is stringifying the *numeric value* of the parameter. Consider `perl -E"say hex(99+1)"`

Comment: @Borodin: Yes. Literals starting with `0x` are just another way how to write integers.

Comment: My point is that there are *two* conversions going on. First, the expression is evaluated as a *number*. Then that number is *stringified* and processed as a hex string.

Comment: However, `perl -E'say hex("A")'` works just fine, so there is more going on behind the curtain.